# change nginx root directory in centos 7

Tags: php, nginx, centos

How to change nginx root directory in centos 7 ?

I create `default.conf` in ‍`/etc/nginx/conf.d` directory and placed the following code

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /var/www/test;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

But when start nginx with `service nginx start` returns this error

> Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

#### Edited

output of **systemctl status nginx.service**

> nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
>
> Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
>
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-07-07 19:21:49 IRDT; 11min ago
>
> Process: 9976 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Process: 10101 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Process: 10099 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Main PID: 9978 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Comment: what output **systemctl status nginx.service**?

Comment: edit my question @MikeFoxtech

Comment: please show **/var/log/nginx/error.log**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nginx -t` to test your configuration

if the error is caused by *multiple server name*,
try deleting this `default_server` from your configuration